# What is it about Bitcoin Core that always makes it so "glitchy" and "buggy"?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I've used Bitcoin Core for many years now. Primarily on Windows. While I appreciate its existence, and in many way, it's structured just as I want and expect it (except some really weird stuff which I've tried to ask about but can't get anyone to explain), my main issue is that I've lost count on the number of times that it just gets "stuck". It freezes. Stops responding. I'm forced to kill and restart it. Often it then takes forever to start up, saying something about "Rescanning" or other wording.

Right now, I've simply slept for six hours with my computer off, and come back to really struggling to get Bitcoin Core back up and running. I don't get how things like that happen. It just seems to randomly decide to break for no reason.

What is it with its code that apparently makes it so flimsy? Is it because it uses so much of the hardware to do all kinds of crypto calculations?

Oftentimes when I've really needed to use it, or make a transaction, I just can't get it to respond. It's so frustrating.

And this is not due to my computer, because it has been the same for numerous different machines and installations and I never have anything weird interfering with it. This general behaviour has not changed no matter how many times I've updated to a new version. It's as if the program is fundamentally unstable/fragile.

I wish I could at least understand why this is happening. I can deal with it, just barely, but it really makes it feel like a chore to use when you always have to be scared that it basically "locks the door on you" temporarily when you really need to "do your banking", just like the physical banks were only open for a very small window a day.

This is not about one single issue, or my current problem. It's about a seemingly never ending stream of similar issues/glitches/freezes/lockouts. Is this out of necessity due to how complex/demanding the software is or something? I just wish its internal work wouldn't affect the GUI, which it very much seems to do.

Comment: Although I don't understand what specifically are you asking for, I can add few things based on my experience in using Windows and Bitcoin Core. 1. Bitcoin Core is similar to Outlook in terms of performance on Windows which is a rich client 2. Works fine for me 3. UI/UX can be improved and there are lot of desktop and mobile apps using bitcoin core as backend which work fine. Examples: Specter, Sparrow, etc.

Comment: @Prayank 1. Sorry, what does Outlook have to do with this? The e-mail suite? 2. Don't know what to say... 3. Never even heard of those, but I'm talking about Bitcoin Core.

Comment: 1. `in terms of performance` 3. Bitcoin Core can be used as backend for other projects

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core is a full node, meaning behind the scenes it's also going and downloading and validating every single block and every single Bitcoin transaction, which would explain why sometimes it's a little laggy. When you first start it up, it has to download all blocks between the last time you opened it and now, validate it all, then scan all of the transactions in there for transactions involving your addresses, which is what it's doing when it says it's "rescanning" or your balance is out of date.

If this is a significant problem for you, I suggest looking into a SPV client like Electrum which offloads that heavy work of maintaining a copy of the blockchain to outside servers. Instead, Electrum will verify things like there being sufficient proof of work on each block it fetches from the server, to ensure that the server can't feed it false data. If you would still like to run a full node, you could also look into running your own Electrum server.

Answer (score -1):

It is a thing called software. Software is ditchy, buggy and glitchy.
That is why Software Engineers developed things like git, bugzilla, linux, ... stackexchange ... hang on? What exactly are you asking?